# MySQL Language translation query

Tags: mysql

[image: **I Used below approach for database**]
I am using multi language supported database. But i don't know how to query translated text from database based on Language.

Here is my DDL for tables. Please ask me if you have any question.

Category Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name_translation_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description_translation_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Language Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `languages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `language_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `language_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Language Translation table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `language_translation` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Language Translation Entry Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `language_translation_entry` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `translation_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `translation_text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Currently i am using this query to get results but it is giving me from only name. I want description also in results.

```
SELECT lte.translation_text  as name FROM catalog_category AS cc
LEFT JOIN language_translation lt ON lt.id = cc.name_translation_id
LEFT JOIN language_translation_entry AS lte ON lte.translation_id = lt.id
LEFT JOIN languages AS l on l.id = lte.language_id
WHERE l.language_code = "en"
```

I need to get translated text from Translation Entry Table for category name and description based on language code in a single query.

Comment: can you please explain Translation table

Comment: Yes, It have id column which is the reference key for catalog_category.name_translation_id and language_translation_entry.translation_id.

Comment: Your query should work, it might be the content of your tables, maybe add some conrete examples. And check why you have `name_translation_id varchar(255)` in `catalog_category` but `id int(10) unsigned` in `language_translation`.

Comment: Yes it is working but through this query i can get only one column result either for name or description but i want to get the result of both columns in single query.

Comment: Okay! Have have been updated the definition of catalog_category table.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you wanted description and name in one query. I posted an answer

Comment: Your ERD shows four tables, none of which are `catalog_category`, `languages`, `language_translation` or `language_translation_entry`

Comment: That is just a example of approach i am using, I found it on Google :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subselects:

```sql
SELECT 
  (select lte.translation_text
   from language_translation_entry AS lte 
   JOIN languages AS l on l.id = lte.language_id
   WHERE lte.translation_id = cc.name_translation_id 
         and l.language_code = "en"
  ) as name,
  (select lte.translation_text
   from language_translation_entry AS lte 
   JOIN languages AS l on l.id = lte.language_id
   WHERE lte.translation_id = cc.description_translation_id 
         and l.language_code = "en"
  ) as description
from catalog_category AS cc
```

This assumes you have max 1 entry for each `(translation_id, laguage_id)`, otherwise this will give you an error, because these subselects can only return one value.

I left out the table `language_translation`, because you probably only use it to get your autoincrement values, and is not required for the join.

An alternative would be to use another `join` for each column you need translated, you can e.g. use

```sql
SELECT lte.translation_text as name,
       lt2.translation_text as description,
FROM catalog_category AS cc
LEFT JOIN language_translation_entry AS lte 
ON lte.translation_id = cc.name_translation_id
LEFT JOIN languages AS l on l.id = lte.language_id
LEFT JOIN language_translation_entry AS lte2 
ON lte2.translation_id = cc.name_translation_id 
   and lte2.language_id = l.id
WHERE l.language_code = "en"
```

where I assume that you want both translation to be the same language.

Btw., `left join` actually works here like a normal `join`, since you use `where l.language_code = "en"`, it has to exists. If you want a real `left join`, you have to move that condition to the `on`-clause, so it can be missing (if there is a possibility that your translations are missing and you still want to get a result from your query). For `description`, it already is allowed to be missing to make the code shorter, otherwise you would have to move the condition from `on` to the `where` clause, so change the last part to

```sql
LEFT JOIN language_translation_entry AS lte2 
ON lte2.translation_id = cc.name_translation_id 
WHERE l.language_code = "en" and lte2.language_id = l.language_id
```

Comment: Thank for reply. Is it possible to get desired result without sub query because have many columns in other tables for the same. It causes performance issue.

Comment: No, your database design limits you to that kind of query. The other option is to add 3 joins for every column you want to translate, which would be even worse and longer. With proper indexes this should be fast enough, but change your varchar-ids (e.g. `description_translation_id varchar(255)` to int too, it requires casting). I removed the join to `language_translation`, because it is not required.

Comment: Okay, I have updated description_translation_id to int. Can you show me an example with join?

Comment: I think this approach have limitation to query. Can you suggestion me any better approach.

Comment: "better" is not a good question without requirements. You can optimize a bit, e.g. use `language_code` (not id) directly in your `language_translation_entry`-table (as in your image), so you could get rid of another `join`. Your approach is a general purpose approach, and it works fine, and with indexes is fast enough, so I'm not sure what you are looking for. An alternative could be to have an extra translation table for all your tables with all columns, e.g. `catalog_category_trans (id, langcode, name, title, description, ...)`, but this is more specialized. It depends on your requirements.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it :)